# Avg and Median -> scenario where they are grossly apart?

Tags: average, median

Can someone cite a "real-world" scenario (something palpable, more easily understood by poorly-educated folks) where the median and the average are grossly far apart and using the average could lead to a bad outcome?

Comment: You either win the lottery or you lose the lottery, with many more losing the lottery.  The median result of the amount of money you are expected to win is zero.  The average result may be a good deal higher depending on how big the prize pool is.  As for "using the average could lead to a bad outcome" ... so long as you use median and average correctly you should always be fine.  Just don't mistake what they actually represent.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have five numbers: 8, 10, 75, 78, 79. The median is 75 because it lies in the middle of the set. However, the average is only 50, being equal to (8 + 10 + 75 + 78 + 79)/5 = 250/5. The average is low because you have two extremely small numbers, and the differences between the three other numbers are small.